# Stylesheet property doesn't apply in elements

Tags: css

When I check my browser `Inspect element` window, I see a warning yellow board /!\ in a element stylesheet property, which indicates my stylesheet class `background-color` property isn't *applied* in the element. Declaring `!important` isn't possible also.

[image: Error]

Also, when I declare the `background-color` property in the own element stylesheet, it works. One from all background color classes I've is:

```
.c-white
{
    background-color: "#fff" /* makes element white */
}
```

The structure is empty yet. So, I'm declaring this class kind in this HTML text:

```
<list class="n-ls-block">
    <li class="c-white"></li>
    <li class="cg-top"></li>
    <li class="cg-normal"></li>
    <li class="cg-strong"></li>
    <li class="cg-deep"></li>
    <li class="c-black"></li>
</list>
```

(There's almost nothing outside to that in its container.)

Comment: What it's shown under the "Computed styles" tab?

Comment: A quick try would be `.n-ls-block .c-white{...}`

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos There is shown the element applied styles. Background color is nothing there.

Comment: @Pangloss `.c-white` is applied to all body elements. I'll give a try, though.

Comment: What is the value of `background-color` in this tab?

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos It's rgba > 0, 0, 0 and 0 (alpha).

Comment: In this case you'd better post your entire css here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quotes around `#fff`.

Comment: God!!! I completely forgot about that!